# What is the real meaning of this stanza?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, usage, rhetoric

I have read the poem “Opportunity” by Walter Malone, but I could not understand the real meaning of the third stanza:

> Dost thou behold thy lost youth all aghast?
> Dost reel from righteous Retribution's blow?
> Then turn from blotted archives of the past
> And find the future's pages white as snow.

Could anyone paraphrase this for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Dost thou behold thy lost youth all aghast? Dost reel from righteous
> Retribution's blow? Then turn from blotted archives of the past And
> find the future's pages white as snow.

Given the title "Opportunity" the first three lines mean, "stop regretting the past", and the last means, "The future is like a new page in a journal. You have the opportunity to write whatever you want there". In other words you can make a new start.

*Stop ruminating about what happened in the past. Focus on building a better future.*

or

*Forget the past and think only of the future.*

Comment: You asked for the meaning of the last stanza. I have given the meaning.  Old Brixtonian gave two line-by-line answers but you didn't like that. You don't say why you find this verse difficult. Is it the grammar? The vocabulary? The fact that it uses metaphor? We can't guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you look with horror at your wasted early life?
>  Do you stagger
> under the clobbering of justified punishment?
>  Then renounce the
> bespattered record of your life so far
>  Make a fresh start and be
> good.

Or

> Look at your life so far. What a mess!
>  And you're being punished
> for it. Quite right!
>  All you do gets written down. So far the
> pages are all smudged.
>  Keep them pristine from now on.